# Simple NodeJS minifier cli app - fs.writeFile only writes to 1 file from list over and over

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, fs

As my first NodeJS app I made a simple CLI Minifier app for HTML, CSS and Javascript files. It works for the most part but one feature. The goal is to have the "all" command read all files in a folder, put the names in an array and write those files minified to a different folder. When I give the CLI "Command: all", console logs all files correctly but will only minify 1 file for as much times as there are files in the folder.

I tried to for...loop through fileArr[] to read and write files from there, after letting 'forEach' push all file names into fileArr[]. This gave the same output as now.

The full working code is added with all features below the code that does not work as intended.
To make the app work you need to have HTML-Minifier installed `npm install html-minifier`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier

The piece of code that does not work as intended, I have added comments to try to make it clearer (some comments in the full working code I wrote for myself and dont necessarily need an answer in this thread):

```
} else if(answer === 'all'){
if (!fs.existsSync("./files/")){ //Checks if folder exists, if not it will create one
                    fs.mkdirSync("./files/");
                }
                //Code that reads the /files/ folder to make a list of all files in there.
                fs.readdir(__dirname + '/files/', function (err, files){ //Files get listed correctly
                    if(err){
                        console.error(err)
                        setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                        return;
                    }
                    let fileArr = []
                    //With forEach I want to minify->write new file->log for every item in the list. 
                    //Console.log shows all seperate items correctly but only 1 item gets minified as much as there are items in the folder
                    files.forEach(function (file){
                        fileArr.push(file) //Files get listed correctly
                        //Part that reads the input file
                      codeIn = file;
                        console.log(codeIn + "    - console.log()") //Files get listed correctly
                      const fileIn = fs.readFile(__dirname + `/files/${codeIn}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => { //For some reason something must go wrong somewhere here. Only 1 file gets minified over and over
                        if(err){
                            console.error(err)
                            setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                            return;
                        } 
                        codeOut = minify(data, { //Minifies input
                            collapseWhitespace: true,
                            removeEmptyElements: true,
                            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                            minifyCSS: true,
                            minifyJS: true
                        });
                        //Part that writes the minified file
                        if (!fs.existsSync("./minified/")){ //Checks if folder 'minified' exists, this is the output folder
                            fs.mkdirSync("./minified/");
                        }
                        fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/minified/${codeIn}`, codeOut, err => {
                            if (err) {
                              console.error(err);
                              setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                              return;
                            }
                            const sizeOutput = minified(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (minified(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb'; //Some calulations with the file sizes for the log file.
                            const sizeBefore = before(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (before(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                            const sizeDifference = (before(codeIn) - minified(codeIn)) + " Bytes - " + ((before(codeIn) - minified(codeIn)) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                            const outputMsg = codeIn + " | Before: " + sizeBefore + " | After: " + sizeOutput + " | Difference: " + sizeDifference
                            logArr.push(outputMsg)
                            console.log('File Sucessfully Minified!')
                            console.log(outputMsg)
                            setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                          });
                    });
                    })
                })
} else {
```

```
//Full Working Code

var minify = require('html-minifier').minify;
const rl = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
const fs = require('fs');

let codeIn;
let codeOut;
let logArr = [];

function minified(filename) {
    var stats = fs.statSync(`./minified/${filename}`);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}
function before(filename, fIsTrue) {
    if(fIsTrue === true){
        var files = '';
    } else {
        var files = 'files/';
    }
    var stats = fs.statSync(`./${files}${filename}`);
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    return fileSizeInBytes;
}
function createLog(){
    const logTime = (new Date().getMinutes()).toString() + (new Date().getSeconds()).toString()
    let logFile = ""
    logFile = logFile + (logArr.toString()).replace(/,/g, "\n")
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/log-${logTime}.txt`, logFile, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                return;
            } 
            console.log(`File log-${logTime}.txt created!`)
            logArr = []
            });
}

function askCommand(){
    rl.question('Command: ', (answer) => {
        if(answer === 'log'){
          createLog()
          setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
        } else if (answer === 'print') {
          let logFile = ""
          logFile = logFile + (logArr.toString()).replace(/,/g, "\n")
          console.log(logFile)
          setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
        } else if(answer === 'log date'){
          logArr.unshift(new Date())
          createLog()
          setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
        } else if(answer === 'help'){
          console.log(`\n \n By default the app will look for files in the './files/' folder \n Minified files will be put in a folder './minified/' \n \n LIST OF POSSIBLE COMMANDS: \n * 'myApp.js' - Enter the filename including extension to minify \n * 'index.html --f' - With ' --f' you can minify files from the same folder as app.js \n * 'print' - Will print the log to the console \n * 'log' - Will create a log.txt file with relevant file sizes. Log is cleared afterwards. \n * 'log date' - Will create a log file with current date time. Log is cleared afterwards. \n * 'help' - Shows the list of possible commands`)
          setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
        } else if(answer === 'all'){
                if (!fs.existsSync("./files/")){ //Checks if folder exists, if not it will create one
                    fs.mkdirSync("./files/");
                }
                //Code that reads the /files/ folder to make a list of all files in there.
                fs.readdir(__dirname + '/files/', function (err, files){ //Files get listed correctly
                    if(err){
                        console.error(err)
                        setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                        return;
                    }
                    let fileArr = []
                    //With forEach I want to minify->write new file->log for every item in the list. 
                    //Console.log shows all seperate items correctly but only 1 item gets minified as much as there are items in the folder
                    files.forEach(function (file){
                        fileArr.push(file) //Files get listed correctly
                        //Part that reads the input file
                      codeIn = file;
                        console.log(codeIn + "    - console.log()") //Files get listed correctly
                      const fileIn = fs.readFile(__dirname + `/files/${codeIn}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => { //For some reason it will not get all items from the list. Only 1 file gets minified over and over
                        if(err){
                            console.error(err)
                            setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                            return;
                        } 
                        codeOut = minify(data, { //Minifies input
                            collapseWhitespace: true,
                            removeEmptyElements: true,
                            removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                            minifyCSS: true,
                            minifyJS: true
                        });
                        //Part that writes the minified file
                        if (!fs.existsSync("./minified/")){
                            fs.mkdirSync("./minified/");
                        }
                        fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/minified/${codeIn}`, codeOut, err => {
                            if (err) {
                              console.error(err);
                              setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                              return;
                            }
                            const sizeOutput = minified(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (minified(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb'; //Some calulations with the file sizes for the log file.
                            const sizeBefore = before(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (before(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                            const sizeDifference = (before(codeIn) - minified(codeIn)) + " Bytes - " + ((before(codeIn) - minified(codeIn)) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                            const outputMsg = codeIn + " | Before: " + sizeBefore + " | After: " + sizeOutput + " | Difference: " + sizeDifference
                            logArr.push(outputMsg)
                            console.log('File Sucessfully Minified!')
                            console.log(outputMsg)
                            setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                          });
                    });
                    })
                })
        } else {
            var bol;
            const answerSplit = answer.split(' --')
            if(answerSplit[1] === 'f'){//In case command --f is given 'bol' is set to true and strPath to nothing. This way it will only look for files in the same folder as app.js. Answer is checked for command
                const strPath = ''
                bol = true;
                miniFy(strPath)
            } else {
                bol = false;
                const strPath = 'files/'
                miniFy(strPath)
            }


        function miniFy(param){ //Function works inside the 'else if' statement but not outside, error is: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
            if (!fs.existsSync("./files/")){
                fs.mkdirSync("./files/");
            }
            codeIn = answerSplit[0].toString();//Gets filename from splitted input
            console.log(param + codeIn + "    - console.log()")
            const fileIn = fs.readFile(`./${param}${codeIn}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
                if(err){
                    console.error(err)
                    setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                    return;
                } 
            codeOut = minify(data, {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeEmptyElements: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyJS: true
            });
            wFile()
        });
        }

        
        function wFile(){  //Function works inside the 'else if' statement but not outside, error is: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
            if (!fs.existsSync("./minified/")){
                fs.mkdirSync("./minified/");
            }
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + `/minified/${codeIn}`, codeOut, err => {
                if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
                return;
                }
                if(bol === true){
                    const sizeOutput = minified(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (minified(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                    const sizeBefore = before(codeIn, true) + ' Bytes - ' + (before(codeIn, true) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                    const sizeDifference = (before(codeIn, true) - minified(codeIn)) + " Bytes - " + ((before(codeIn, true) - minified(codeIn)) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                    var outputMsg = codeIn + " | Before: " + sizeBefore + " | After: " + sizeOutput + " | Difference: " + sizeDifference
                } else {
                    const sizeOutput = minified(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (minified(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                    const sizeBefore = before(codeIn) + ' Bytes - ' + (before(codeIn) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                    const sizeDifference = (before(codeIn) - minified(codeIn)) + " Bytes - " + ((before(codeIn) - minified(codeIn)) / 1024).toFixed(3) + 'Kb';
                    var outputMsg = codeIn + " | Before: " + sizeBefore + " | After: " + sizeOutput + " | Difference: " + sizeDifference
                }
                logArr.push(outputMsg)
                console.log('File Sucessfully Minified!')
                console.log(outputMsg)
                setTimeout(askCommand, 250)
            });
        }
    }
})
}
askCommand()
```

Comment: Make `codeIn` a local variable inside of the `.forEach()` callback so your various loop iterations are not conflicting.  Remember, you have asynchronous code in here so all iterations of the loop will be in flight at the same time.  You cannot share any variables between loop iterations.

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to be the problem. Its working now.